# My iPhone has decided to wipe all Firefox bookmarks out of the blue

Tags: iphone, ios, firefox

From yesterday on, my iPhone decided to just delete every single bookmark from bookmarks and now I have nothing on Firefox. Why does this happen? I have connected the Firefox accounts on my Macbook and my iPhone and the boomarks on iPhone and Macbook were always in sync, until now.

Comment: iPhone's do not do things on their own like this, you must have told it to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by signing out and in again to my Firefox account on my iPhone, but this is not a good solution, if you ask me.

Comment: Have you told the developer of Firefox about the issue?